# Error on set ImageView resource in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I am new to Android. I am working on an app. It has a 3*3 grid layout with an image view in each cell. I want to set resource of images randomly from an array of drawables. I used .setImageResource() for each one but when I run the app it crashes.

Here's the error message from [log cat](http://uupload.ir/files/h45v_untitled.png).

And here is my XML and java code.

**activity_game.xml**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.leila.makesquare.GameActivity"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="3">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:gravity="fill">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:gravity="fill">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:gravity="fill">

          <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:gravity="fill">

         <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

**GameActivity.java**

```
package com.example.leila.makesquare;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GameActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int[] squares=new int[]
    { 
            R.drawable.brgy,
            R.drawable.bygr,
            R.drawable.bygr2,
            R.drawable.gbry,
            R.drawable.gyrb,
            R.drawable.gyrb2,
            R.drawable.rbyg,
            R.drawable.rgby,
            R.drawable.rybg
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        ArrayList<Integer> jj=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            jj.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(jj);

        ImageView imageView0=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView0);
        ImageView imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView imageView3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView imageView4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageView imageView5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        ImageView imageView6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        ImageView imageView7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        ImageView imageView8=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);


        int q0=squares[jj.get(0)];
        int q1=squares[jj.get(1)];
        int q2=squares[jj.get(2)];
        int q3=squares[jj.get(3)];
        int q4=squares[jj.get(4)];
        int q5=squares[jj.get(5)];
        int q6=squares[jj.get(6)];
        int q7=squares[jj.get(7)];
        int q8=squares[jj.get(8)];

        imageView0.setImageResource(q0);
        imageView1.setImageResource(q1);
        imageView2.setImageResource(q2);
        imageView3.setImageResource(q3);
        imageView4.setImageResource(q4);
        imageView5.setImageResource(q5);
        imageView6.setImageResource(q6);
        imageView7.setImageResource(q7);
        imageView8.setImageResource(q8);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the crash Log from your Log cat

Comment: This is a very ordinary code. It could be better if you dig google for _GridLayout_ example

Comment: And this code is bizzare. You don't need jj array if you are anyways hardcoding 0-9 everywhere. you dont even need q0-q8 as you can directly use squares[0] in imageView0.setImageResource(squares[0]).

Comment: Plus as @Piyush mentioned until your requirement is a very non standard grid, this is not the right way to implement a GridLayout

Comment: Use image loading libraries to load images, your app crashes just because of your device can not allocate enough memory to load that high resolution images in that particular cell of your grid view, So go with Fresco, Glide, Picaso or Universal Image loader library

Comment: this error cause by image pixel, use resizer app

Comment: thank you all.It was the size problem.I resized the images and the app works properly. @JinsLukose

Comment: you are always welcome @LeilaR

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a closing angle bracket at your 5th linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="110dp"
android:layout_row="1"
android:layout_column="1"
android:gravity="fill"
```

Comment: This may be not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here You have not close ImageView closing bracket i.e. "/>"
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"

</LinearLayout>
And here you have not close Linear Layout closing bracket i.e. "/>"
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:gravity="fill"

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand,all linear layout and image view open/close brackets are the same

Comment: This is not an answer !

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageView tag isn't closed. Try

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView0"/>
```

And try giving us the logs

[EDIT]
As from the edit you Activity code is very bad, try reading more about GridViews and the coding practice in Java and Android to improve your code and coding skills.

Comment: This is not an answer !